# UDP Socket: java.net.SocketException: socket closed

Tags: java, sockets, udp

MessageCreator: Encapsulate and resolve ports and device unique identifiers.

```
public class MessageCreator {
    private static final String HEADER_PORT = "to port:";
    private static final String HEADER_SN = "My sn:";
    
    public static String buildWithPort(int port) {
        return HEADER_PORT + port;
    }
    
    public static int parsePort(String data) {
        if (data.startsWith(HEADER_PORT)) {
            return Integer.parseInt(data.substring(HEADER_PORT.length()));
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    public static String buildWithSn(String sn) {
        return HEADER_SN + sn;
    }
    
    public static String parseSn(String data) {
        if (data.startsWith(HEADER_SN)) {
            return data.substring(HEADER_SN.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

UdpProvider: Loop to listen to a specific port, then parse the received data, determine whether the data conforms to the predetermined format, get the sender's response port from it, and respond with the uniquely identified UUID value to the UDP searcher.

```
public class UdpProvider {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String sn = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Provider provider = new Provider(sn);
        provider.start();
        // Warning: Result of 'InputStream.read()' is ignored 
        System.in.read();
        provider.exit();
    }
    
    private static class Provider extends Thread {
        
        private DatagramSocket ds = null;
        private boolean done = false;
        
        private final String sn;
        
        public Provider(String sn) {
            super();
            this.sn = sn;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                ds = new DatagramSocket(20000);
                while (!done) {
                    final byte[] buf = new byte[512];
                    DatagramPacket receivePak = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                    ds.receive(receivePak);
                    
                    String ip = receivePak.getAddress().getHostAddress();
                    int port = receivePak.getPort();
                    byte[] receivePakData = receivePak.getData();
                    String receiveData = new String(receivePakData, 0, /*receivePakData.length*/receivePak.getLength());
                    
                    System.out.println("received from -> ip: " + ip + ", port: " + port + ", data: " + receiveData);
                    
                    
                    int responsePort = MessageCreator.parsePort(receiveData.trim());
                    
                    if (responsePort != -1) {
                        String responseData = MessageCreator.buildWithSn(sn);
                        byte[] bytes = responseData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        DatagramPacket responsePak = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length,
                                /*InetAddress.getLocalHost()*/
                                receivePak.getAddress(),
                                responsePort);
                        
                        ds.send(responsePak);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                close();
            }
            
        }
        
        public void exit() {
            
            done = true;
            close();
        }
        
        public void close() {
            if (ds != null) {
                ds.close();
                ds = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UdpSearcher: Listening to a specific port and sending a LAN broadcast, sending a broadcast sets the listening port in the data, so you need to turn on listening first to finish before you can send a broadcast, and once you receive the response data, you can parse the device information

```java
public class UdpSearcher {
    private static final int LISTENER_PORT = 30000;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Listener listener = listen();
        sendBroadcast();
    
        // Warning: Result of 'InputStream.read()' is ignored 
        System.in.read();

        List<Device> deviceList = listener.getDevicesAndClose();
        for (Device device : deviceList) {
            System.out.println(device);
        }
    }
    
    public static void sendBroadcast() throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
        String sendData = MessageCreator.buildWithPort(LISTENER_PORT);
        byte[] sendDataBytes = sendData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        DatagramPacket sendPak = new DatagramPacket(sendDataBytes, sendDataBytes.length);
        sendPak.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"));
        sendPak.setPort(20000);
        ds.send(sendPak);
        ds.close();
    }
    
    public static Listener listen() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Listener listener = new Listener(LISTENER_PORT, countDownLatch);
        listener.start();
        
        countDownLatch.await();
        return listener;
    }
    
    private static class Listener extends Thread {
        private final int listenPort;
        private DatagramSocket ds = null;
        private boolean done = false;
        private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
        private List<Device> devices = new ArrayList<>();
        
        public Listener(int listenPort, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
            super();
            this.listenPort = listenPort;
            this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            countDownLatch.countDown();
            try {
                ds = new DatagramSocket(listenPort);
                while (!done) {
                    final byte[] buf = new byte[512];
                    DatagramPacket receivePak = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                    ds.receive(receivePak);
                    
                    String ip = receivePak.getAddress().getHostAddress();
                    int port = receivePak.getPort();
                    byte[] data = receivePak.getData();
                    String receiveData = new String(data, 0, /*data.length*/receivePak.getLength());
                    String sn = MessageCreator.parseSn(receiveData);
    
                    System.out.println("received from -> ip: " + ip + ", port: " + port + ", data: " + receiveData);
    
    
                    if (sn != null) {
                        Device device = new Device(ip, port, sn);
                        devices.add(device);
                    }
                }
                
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                close();
            }
            
        }
        
        public void close() {
            if (ds != null) {
                ds.close();
                ds = null;
            }
        }
    
        public List<Device> getDevicesAndClose() {
            done = true;
            close();
            return devices;
        }
        
    }
    
    private static class Device {
        private String ip;
        private int port;
        private String sn;
        
        public Device(String ip, int port, String sn) {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port;
            this.sn = sn;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Device{" +
                    "ip='" + ip + '\'' +
                    ", port=" + port +
                    ", sn='" + sn + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

UdpProvider and UdpSearcher worked fine and printed corrresponding data until I input a char sequence  from keyboard follwed by pressing `Enter` key on each console window, both threw an exception on this line `ds.receive(receivePak);` :
[image]

Comment: why do you exit? `provider.start(); provider.exit();`

Comment: @ScaryWombat em, after UdpSearcher found UdpProvider and printed message, I think it's time  to enter any char sequence to exit the program

Comment: Looks like it will exit immediately though.  You should use join, and wait for the Thread to exit.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks...But I found other people can run these program normally on idea, without prompting a warning:`Result of 'InputStream.read()' is ignored ` on `System.in.read()`,I wonder if I missed something or got something wrong.

Comment: threw on which line?

Comment: @user253751 Both UdpProvider and UdpSearcher threw on this line:`ds.receive(receivePak);`

Comment: Oh I see now. Isn't that exception thrown because you closed the socket?